# Is the [help] tag helpful? 

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The [help](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/help) tag seems a little pointless, but there are 23 questions tagged as help, don't you agree?

Comment: I think it's fair to say that any question posted to SF is asking for help, which makes the tag rather redundant.

Answer (score 11):

I agree. It is stupid and should be culled, leaving the rest of the herd stronger than before.

Comment: Is there a way to edit tags that doesn't bump Qs back to the homepage? I'm a measly <10k user =(

Comment: No, any tag edits will force them to the front page, unless it's done by the SE devs I think.

Comment: Don't worry about bumping to the front page. Just do them in bursts of 4-5 and you'll be fine.

Comment: I've killed all the questions tagged with [help], can we kill the tag now?

Comment: It'll go away automatically.

Comment: Just need to watch the tag perhaps and retag anything new appears..

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, this tag is less than worthless :-)

Comment: If we interpret that as a double-negative, it becomes "worth"... ;-)